# Is there an alternative to transform loader in webpack 5 to get pdfkit working?

Tags: webpack

I have a project that is based off of this example:
https://github.com/blikblum/pdfkit-webpack-example

that generates a pdf client side.

I am trying to update to webpack 5, but a few things:

- transform-loader is archived
- webpack 5 deprecated the querystring approach to loaders

has anyone gotten pdfkit to work in webpack 5?

Comment: Same problem here, can't bundle pdfmake with Webpack 5 for the moment :/

Comment: ended up getting it working with a combination of provide plugin for process and polyfills. check this issue: https://github.com/blikblum/pdfkit-webpack-example/issues/9